# How to improve this animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs on the same line. You can check the example here: http://yoyo.ro/abw just scroll to the bottom of the page to the three boxes: Made to Measure, Instagram and Video Tracking.

When I click the left one, I want the other two to slide to the right and some text to appear. I tried to do it, but it seems that I complicated it so much and it isn't even smooth.

```
function hideTest(){
         $(".instagram").addClass("slideout");
         $(".videotracking").addClass("slideout");
         $(".instagram").animate({left:"150%"},500);
         $(".videotracking").animate({left:"150%"},500);
         }
function showTest(){
         $(".instagram").animate({left:"33.3%"},500);
         $(".videotracking").animate({left:"66.6%"},500);
         $(".instagram").removeClass("slideout");
         $(".videotracking").removeClass("slideout");
         }

     $(".madetomeasure").on('click',function(){
         var testwidth = $(this).find(".vc_btn3-container").width();
         $(this).find(".vc_btn3-container").css("width", testwidth);

     if(!$(this).hasClass("openslide")){
         hideTest();
         $(".madetomeasure").addClass("openslide");
         $(this).find(".txtbox").animate({left:0},500);}

      else {
            $(this).find(".txtbox").animate({left:"-100%"},500);
            $(".madetomeasure").removeClass("openslide");
            showTest();
             }

         });
```

here is the css relevant to the JS

```
   .txtbox{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        width: 66.5%;
        display:none;
        left:-100%;
        padding:0px 15px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;}
   .instagram, .videotracking{position:static;}
   .instagram {left:33.3%;}
   .videotracking{left:66.5%;}
   .instagram.slideout{position:absolute;}
   .videotracking.slideout{position:absolute;}
   .madetomeasure .button{
     z-index:1;
     height:300px;
     background: url(http://yoyo.ro/abw/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/instagram.jpg) 100% 30% !important;
     border: none !important;}
   .madetomeasure.openslide {width:100%;}
   .madetomeasure.openslide .wpb_wrapper {display:flex;}
   .madetomeasure.openslide .txtbox {display:block;}
```

Thank you so much for the patience... :) I really appreciate it

Comment: You ought to use an `.active` class CSS and jQuery combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, your problem of smoothness is because:

1. **jQuery change the inline styling of the animated element per frame**. That is a lot of work and you can actually see the action if you inspect your element when it's animating.
2. CSS does poorly on animating `left` and `right`. There are many articles about this but here's one if you don't want to search: https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/

---

### The Solution

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kv5twc64/1/

The solution is very common, and is used by many CSS libraries, a trick using `.active`, CSS animation and some JS.

Here I used the `transition` property for `.card`:

```
.card {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  max-width:33.333%;
  position:relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-out;
}
```

If you don't know, `transition` will create a tweening effect when the elements' property has changed.

And here is the trick: By using `~` selecting the siblings in CSS and the `transform` property:

```
.card.active .desc {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.card.active ~.card {
  transform: translateX(66.666vw);
}
```

There are several upsides on using CSS in this case:

- You can simplify your JS. The JS became:

  ```
  $(function(){
      $(".card").eq(0).click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    })
  })
  ```
- You can improve webpage performance
- You can have more choices on (simple) easing functions in CSS (jQuery only offers "swing" by default). Check this out: http://easings.net You can do something like this:

  ```
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  ```

Hope this can help. But the lesson here is: **Use CSS rather than JS when you can!**

---

P.S. `66.666vw` means 2/3 the width of the viewport width.